# android show rectangle on camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hi I want to show a rectangle in camera so that when the user takes snap only the region inside the rectangle can be processed. Any idea how can I do it? And the rectangle size can be resized by dragging along the corners.

I am not calling the camera application. I am using the camera API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi I solved the problem using this tutorial, [see here](http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/)
If the link goes missing some day I have kept a pdf [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sx97jgmd32dezhy/adblogcat.com-A%20camera%20preview%20with%20a%20bounding%20box%20like%20Google%20goggles.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Nice to know it helped.

Comment: Both links broken

Answer (score 3):

You can see my open source application http://code.google.com/p/android-palmprint-api , in SVN you can see the source code. [image: The draw a AR information on real time camera image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to draw a rectangle that has size as you desire. Then you just need to set that size for preview frame, and when you get the result return from onPreviewFrame , you will process on that data.
You can refer the ViewfinderView class of Xzing source [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java)
to learn how to draw a rectangle in camera preview.
and refer CameraConfigurationManager,PreviewCallback,CameraManager also in xzing source to learn how to set preview size and process result data return from camera driver.
Hope this help you.